# Как создавать ребусы в С++?

Tags: c++, комбинаторика, арифметика

Нужно отгадать ребус, где вместо буков будут числа от 0 до 9(разные буквы, разные числа). Нужен пример для А, дальше разберусь. Какую команду использовать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто перебирать все варианты цифр?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, проще всего - перебор. Если под конкретное количество букв - что-то типа

```
for(int A = 1; A <= 9; ++A)
{
    for(int B = 1; B <= 9; ++B)
    {
        if (A == B) continue;
        for(int C = 0; C <= 9; ++C)
        {
            if (A == C) continue;
            if (B == C) continue;
            // расписываю подробное выражение для понятности :)
            if (A*100+B*10+С + A*100+C*10+B == B*100+C*10+A)
                cout << A << " " << B << " " << С << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

(Ну, или от 0 - если такой вариант проходит. В вашем первом задании он годится только для C).

Если букв много - можно перестановками "01234565789", но тогда нужно несколько править перестановку, так как нужны не все 10! вариантов, а только для определенного количества букв. Боюсь, что рассказать, как это делать - явно выходит за рамки вопроса, и требует квалификации, которой, судя по вопросу, вы пока не обладаете...

И в общем же случае имеет смысл писать свой синтаксический анализатор таких выражений.

Я как-то такой написал для себя, с тех пор для меня все эти задачки - так, набрать в командной строке и получить ответ :)